# Using Swagger with javascript on client-site without NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, client, swagger

How I can use Swagger-generated API client source on client-site (normal browser application without NodeJs)?

In a first test I generated a javascript client for Swaggers' petstore API (https://petstore.swagger.io/v2) using [editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io)

The generated code is containing a index.js which provides access to constructors for public API classes, which I try to embed and use in my web application.

The documentation describes the usage of the API like so:

```js
  var SwaggerPetstore = require('swagger_petstore');
  var defaultClient = SwaggerPetstore.ApiClient.instance;

  // Configure API key authorization: api_key
  var api_key = defaultClient.authentications['api_key'];
  api_key.apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';
  // Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. "Token" (defaults to null)
  //api_key.apiKeyPrefix = 'Token';

  var apiInstance = new SwaggerPetstore.PetApi();

  var petId = 789; // Number | ID of pet to return


  var callback = function(error, data, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
    }
  };
  apiInstance.getPetById(petId, callback);
```

This works fine for NodeJs applications. But how I can use the API for conventional client-site web-apps inside the browser? For such applications the nodejs function **require** does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js

The example has cross origin problem, but it should work in your own project

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src='//unpkg.com/swagger-client' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script>

var specUrl = '//petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json'; // data urls are OK too 'data:application/json;base64,abc...'
SwaggerClient.http.withCredentials = true; // this activates CORS, if necessary

var swaggerClient = new SwaggerClient(specUrl)
      .then(function (swaggerClient) {
          return swaggerClient.apis.pet.addPet({id: 1, name: "bobby"}); // chaining promises
      }, function (reason) {
         console.error("failed to load the spec" + reason);
      })
      .then(function(addPetResult) {
         console.log(addPetResult.obj);
         // you may return more promises, if necessary
      }, function (reason) {
          console.error("failed on API call " + reason);
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  check console in browser's dev. tools
</body>
</html>
```